# What happened with Jquery removeOption

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an error in my code - Object doesn't support this property or method when calling removeOption on a JQuery selector. I cannot find this function in the Jquery API. Is that some old method that is now obsolete? What is the new version? Jquery version is 1.3.2

The technique is shown here: http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/

Comment: Are you thinking of [this plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/) perhaps? (Or maybe [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr)?)

Comment: May a piece of code be better... What do you wish to remov and form where?

Comment: @lonesomeday Is that a plugin? It looks like Jquery feature demonstration?

Comment: See [Github](https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins) page. It's the `selectboxes` plugin.

Comment: Yes, it is really a plugin. Thanks! Do you know if it is compatible with Jquery 1.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really was the selectboxes plugin missing, thanks lonesomeday for that. @lonesomeday if you add an answer I will acceprt it.